# CMake - How to install(DIRECTORY) in install(TARGETS)?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

My objective of this code is to copy over a static lib with a folder of includes into another directory.

The new directory will have the structure

```
output_dir
    ├───include
    ├───lib
         └───win64
```

I have two `install` lines of CMake code that I  want to reduce to one. First, I install the lib target to `output_dir/lib/win64` and the `include` directory to `output_dir/include`.

```
add_library(lib STATIC test.cpp )

target_include_directories(lib 
    PUBLIC 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

install(TARGETS lib
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION 
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir/lib/win64
)

install(DIRECTORY
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        DESTINATION
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir/include
)
```

I'd like to effectively reduce the two install commands to one, here is my best attempt at doing so. The static `lib`  library gets copied over correctly but the directories get ignored.

```
install(TARGETS lib
        ARCHIVE
            DESTINATION 
                ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir/lib/win64
        PUBLIC_HEADER
            DESTINATION
                ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir/
        INCLUDES
            DESTINATION
                ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir/     
)
```

I know the error is with public_header, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only need the `PUBLIC_HEADER` argument in the `install()` command, not the `INCLUDES` argument. However, your `PUBLIC_HEADER` argument will not grab any header files, because the [`PUBLIC_HEADER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/PUBLIC_HEADER.html) property for the `lib` target has not been set. Try something like this:

```
add_library(lib STATIC test.cpp)

target_include_directories(lib 
    PUBLIC 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

# List the headers we want to declare as public for installation.
set(MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyHeader.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/MyHeader2.hpp
    ...
)

# Tell the target these headers are "public".
set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS}")

install(TARGETS lib
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir/lib/win64
    PUBLIC_HEADER
        DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output_dir   
)
```

Comment: Can I skip listing out the headers and just do:

`set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)`

Comment: Nope it didnt work. `Error  CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:25 (install):
  install PUBLIC_HEADER given directory`

Comment: My include folder has another folder.  So I guess I have to stick to the directory method.

Comment: No, they must be listed in a semicolon-separated list, which is why there are quotes around the variable `MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS`.

Comment: @j__gt If you have multiple/nested include directories, you could do something like `file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS *.hpp)` instead. But using `GLOB` is not recommended, as CMake will not detect changes to your headers files.

Comment: @squareskittles I suggest that you add the semicolon-separated list part - and the need for quotes - to your answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If it is of any interest for one of you, here is the code I came up with to add `spdlog` include directory (including nested subdirectories).
It indeed uses `GLOB_RECURSE`, but I could not find a better way.

NB: CMake >= 3.23 needed (for `FILE_SET`).

```
set(Target logger)
add_library(${Target} SHARED logger.cpp)

# finding recursively all the header files
file(GLOB_RECURSE spdlog_headers
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/logger_interface/spdlog/include/*.h)
target_sources(${Target} PUBLIC FILE_SET HEADERS 
    BASE_DIRS logger_interface/spdlog/include
    FILES ${spdlog_headers})
set_target_properties(${Target} PROPERTIES FILE_SET spdlog_headers)
set_target_properties(${Target} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "logger.h") # my main include file

set(InstallDir ${Target}) # with skbuild
set(InstallDir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/${Target}) # with cmake normal compilation
install(
    TARGETS logger
    FILE_SET HEADERS DESTINATION ${InstallDir}/include
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${InstallDir}/include
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${InstallDir}/bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${InstallDir}/lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${InstallDir}/lib)
```